# Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = only updates to Labels are allowed

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = only updates to Labels are allowed
```

when redeploying stack

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth monitoring
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, as *Ryabchenko Alexander* said, docker configs cannot be updated, [see moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35048).

In one approach you can remove the services that use the new configs, with the command `docker service rm service_name`.

Then remove the config with `docker config rm config_name` and redeploy the stack to update the config and recreate the removed services.

**Update:** see [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35048#issuecomment-575593409) if it is necessary to have no downtime.

Comment: This approach is better than removing the whole stack!

Comment: by `service config rm config_name`
you saved my day, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 8):

The suggested *removing stack/service* approach brings **DOWNTIME**.

Fortunately, there is a tricky workaround for this issue without downtime. Simply set a name for your config/secret and change that name with help of environment variables every time you run the `docker stack deploy` command:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    configs:
      - source: nginxconf
        target: /etc/nginx/foobar.conf
configs:
  nginxconf:
    name: nginx.conf-${CONFIG_VERSION:-0}
    file: ./nginx.conf
```

For the next deployments, change that variable first and then, run `docker stack deploy`:

```
CONFIG_VERSION=1 docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35048#issuecomment-424372653).

Comment: Note that you get the same error, if you use the same CONFIG_VERSION twice. I use a wrapper deploy -script that sets it either to CI build number or export CONFIG_VERSION=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%m%s)

Answer (score 2):

You can also publish a new conf, versioning it in the name.

I use yml files to deploy and update stacks. If I change a conf file I rename the reference in the yml file (i.e. from `conf-v1` to `conf-v2`) and deploy again: docker creates a new conf and refers to it.

Pros:

- no labels error
- safest on docker auto rollback if deploy fails (if `conf-v2` has breaking changes rollback makes the stack refer to `conf-v1` again, I suppose)

Cons:

- lots of conf to be removed

Comment: like this comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35048#issuecomment-575593409

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35048

The only way to update config is to remove stack and redeploy it

```
docker stack rm <my_stack_name>
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth <my_stack_name>
```